# Can an Entity Framework Context return a class that inherits a Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an Entity Framework 5 Code First DbContext

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have to implement an interface but don't want to pollute my model so I create a

```
public class ProductEx : Product, ISomeInterface
{
    public bool ISomeInterface.SomeMethod() { return false; }
}
```

I know I could do:

```
var query = from p in context.Products
            select new ProductEx { p.ProductId, p.Name };
```

But since the DbContext already returns a dynamic proxy (because of change tracking / lazy loading) maybe there is a better approach. I am thinking about something like this:

```
var query = from p in context.Products.As<ProductEx>()
            select p;
```

the entities should be a dynamic proxy inherited from ProductEx.

Is there a way to achive this?

Comment: Have you thought about using partial classes? You can have properties in one file, and methods in another. Yes interface would be implemented by `Product`, but at leasy you will have optical separation.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to You can create a wrapper for product:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductEx : Product, ISomeInterface
{
    private readonly Product _product;

    public ProductEx(Product product) {
        this._product = product;
    }

    public bool ISomeInterface.SomeMethod() { return false; }

    public override int ProductId
    { 
        get { return this._product.ProductId; }
        set { this._product.ProductId = value; }
    }

    public override string Name
    { 
        get { return this._product.Name; }
        set { this._product.Name = value; }
    }
}
```

Then you can query liko so:

```
var query = from p in context.Products
        select new ProductEx(p);
```

Comment: This woule be a working solution. But that would mean a lot of work since in the big picture I would have a lot more models with a lot more properties.